# Cannot select index value for ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedindex

When I try to load some data and set the index of ComboBox accordingly it gives me an error that "0" is not a valid number of SelectedIndex

The combobox definitely has more than 0 items in it.  Those are added properly.  The number that the index is supposed to be set to is read in properly as well, but the index will not be set.  It doesn't matter if I hard-code a number of set it from the file.

A code snippet:

### CB is the combobox control.

```
((System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)ctrlToSet).Text = n["Text"].InnerText;
string s = n["SelectedIndex"].InnerText;
int nd = 0;
int.TryParse(s, out nd);
CB.SelectedIndex = nd;
```

Comment: This is sort of resolved.  Not entirely sure what the problem was but I worked around it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve.
But I can make of your post. Is that you are trying to set data from one combobox to another?
This is the code I would use to achieve that.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox2.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

I would like to make comment on your question, but I can't.

[image: Description]

If I select 4 in this example, 4 will be selected in corresponding combobox.

Comment: I am not setting one from another.  I am loading the saved state of a combobox as well as all the saved elements from it.

All the elements load.  The number from the saved index loads into a variable fine.  But when I try to set the index it fails.